# Jetpack Compose: How to draw shaped border?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, border, shapes

I'd like to create a bubble outline for text in my application, but I'm noticing that by changing the value of 'border' in modifier, I only change the color of the border of the view instead of the shape.

```
            modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface).background(Color.Red),
            shape = ChatBubbleShape
        ) {}
```

What do I need to modify so that the colored border is the custom shape, instead of the view rectangle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `border` modifier [variant](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).border(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)) with the `shape` parameter.

```
Text(
    "Text",
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(width = 2.dp, color = Red, shape = CircleShape)
        .padding(10.dp)
)
```